# CSS Elements working on actual page but not pulling from stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with some css stylings on my site and hoping you guys can help.

Heres my code:

```html
<style>
    .loginform {
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .memberslogin {
        color: #404040;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    
    .btn.btn-primary.loginbutton {
        margin-bottom: 80px;
    }

</style>
<body style="background: none;">

<?php include('header.php') ?>

    <div class="container">
       <h4 class="memberslogin">Members Login:</h4>
        
            <form class="loginform" action="login_create.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..">
                </div>
                <input class=" btn btn-primary loginbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        
    </div>
```

The styling works fine when styled within the page. However I have these exact same classes and styling within my style.css but when I remove the on page styling none of the effects take place.

```html
<head>
 <title>Title</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="richmondcss.css">
```

As you can see I have linked my style sheet last which should override any bootstrap elements if I am not mistaken?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You said "style.css" but your file is "richmondcss.css". Which is it? And are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: have you done a hard refresh? what happens when you view the source of richmondcss.css in the browser?

Comment: most likely a filepath problem. The above only works if "richmondcss.css" is in the same folder as your html (or php) page

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class on the body tag which will represent your app.

e.g.

```
<body class="the-login-app">...
```

and then prefix all of your custom css with this class...

```
.the-login-app .btn.btn-primary.loginbutton{
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

This is called namespacing. It will not only work but help you with debugging as your project gets bigger. For example if you see an element in debugger hit by a class which starts with "the-login-app" you are confident that css code is yours :)

In the end, try to research and familiarize with the priority of the selectors... All things equal, in-file one will precede. If you want to override bootstrap you need to define more precise selector than bootstrap one, as explained above(which I don't recommend to start with)...

Try to learn bootstrap more. I am sure you will discover that you didn't need your intervention at all...

Comment: so I can't style the form as a whole using the custom class I created? I have to style to elements using the bootstrap classes? because using the body class followed by my form class still doesn't work. e.g .the-login-app .loginform { style } still doesn't apply styling

Comment: Which element? The selector you mentioned ".the-login-app .loginform" hits the form, and form is invisible element by definition...

Comment: It's all good ntadic I took your suggestion and did a bit more research on bootstrap classes and found an answer I was looking for.

Thankyou so much for your assistance